# Where can I find registration information of a private aircraft registered in Germany?

Tags: aircraft-registration, germany

Is there any way (website, database etc.) where I can get the registration information of a privately-owned general aviation aircraft registered in Germany?

<sup>(Germany has pretty extensive privacy laws, but it would seem that aircraft registrations should be a little bit transparent and verifiable...)</sup>

Comment: What information do you need to know, and what information do you have on the aircraft (e.g. Mode S address, registration, type)

Comment: I have the D-XXXX registration, but wanted to know the certification class, owner, manufacturing year, etc. (The sort of thing that the [Transport Canada](http://wwwapps.tc.gc.ca/Saf-Sec-Sur/2/CCARCS-RIACC/ADet.aspx?id=12153&rfr=RchSimpRes.aspx?cn=%7c%7c&mn=%7c%7c&sn=%7c%7c&on=BUFFALO%7c&m=%7c%7c) database provides)

Comment: The document is called "Luftfahrzeugrolle" and held by the LBA. They can only give information to a third party if the owner agrees to it and if a fee is paid. [Here is the German Wikipedia entry](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luftfahrzeugrolle) on that topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think the information is accessible on a public website.

According to the [German wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luftfahrzeugrolle) the Luftfahrtbundesamt (LBA, the German Civil Aviation Authorities) cannot publish the information for data protection law reasons.

On their [website](https://www.lba.de/DE/Technik/Verkehrszulassung/Hinweise/Auskuenfte.html) (in German) they state that they do release information to members of the public at a fee (they love that here).

A little bit of link-clicking later you will find that you have to pay 40 euros. I am not sure whether they can release the name of the owner.

The law (Luftverkehrsgesetz) governing the information in the register can be found [here](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/luftvg/__64.html).

Answer (score 0):

So, while this site is not officially sanctioned by any government, it is quite extensive. Accuracy and currency of data can vary, but there are other websites you can use to verify the source.

Finding single aircraft is the easy part. However getting an entire list of a specific country's registry, whilst I know is possible, may require you subscribe at a certain level to gain that functionality.

AeroTransport Data Bank (ATDB)

http://www.aerotransport.org

Answer (score 0):

Airframes could be worth a try. Doesn't provide all the information you're looking for, but it's a beginning at least. I'm myself using it on work whenever I have to know an aircrafts type.

 
    http://www.airframes.org